# Как сделать, чтобы окно не скрывалось за другими окнами?

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть главный фрейм, открытый в полноэкранном режиме (`win.overrideredirect(1)` и `win.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (win.winfo_screenwidth,win.winfo_screenheight)`)

Если я открываю какой-либо виджет нажатием кнопки и нажимаю на главный фрейм, то виджет пропадает из поля зрения (скрывается за ним). Как можно сделать, чтобы при нажатии на фрейм, окно открытого виджета не скрывалось за ним? Возможно ли это вообще?

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл решение:

```py
def objectInTop(self,*objName):
   for o in objName:
      o.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
```